# Browser config to bypass host file

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to force two different browsers to use two different host files?  Can you package the host file into a published app to override the local host file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is, the way i see it is when you call a web page it will use a defined set/list

1. cached dns
2. local host file
3. DNS server

Unless your app could use a predefined bypass list or something built in?

Answer (score 0):

If your browser is Chrome then you can provide DNS entries on the command line. This is very useful for testing against websites that are still in development on an internal IP address:

```
chrome.exe --host-resolver-rules="MAP example.com 127.0.0.1"
```